# Digital root, practical applications?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, roots

The digital root, can it be useful for anything?

I've read that the digital root can be used to check the correctness of multiplication. But my feeling is that its very error prone and can not always be exact.

I wonder why the digital root is even defined, must have some sort of usage, but is it just there for games and fun or can it be useful?

Here is an example of the application on multiplication:
$$12345\cdot3451=42672595$$

The digital root of lefthand side:

- multiplicand $12345$ is $1+2+3+4+5=15\rightarrow1+5=6$.
- multiplier $3451$ is $3+4+5+1=13\rightarrow1+3=4$.

The digital root of lefthand side is $6\cdot4 = 24$ is $1+4 = 5$.

The digital root of righthand side:

$4+2+6+7+2+5+9+5 = 40 = 4+0 = 4$.

Compare left and right side:
$$5 \neq 4$$

hence the multiplication is incorrect.

To reiterate the basic question I have is, will the digital root always be useful or will it be too error prone to be useful?

Comment: It's not that digital roots for checking calculations are error-prone,  it's that they don't catch all the errors you can make.  For instance, if you switch two digits accidentally, the digital root test will still return a positive result.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for clarifying that. There is even something called additive persistence, meaning the number of times one add together the digits. But I dont know if that also has any practical applications. Seems both can never be useful?

Comment: Well $\,12345\cdot 3451= 42602595$ (not $42672595$) and the d.r. of $6\cdot 4$ is $2+4=6$ so that you should have obtained $6=6$ and not $5\neq 4$ : the thing is of interest... at least here!

Comment: Suppose you had the correct product ($42602595$). Checking the digital roots might have helped you realise something was wrong when you wrote $6⋅4=24$ is $1+4=5$ [sic].

Comment: Which question are you asking, whether it is useful for anything, or whether the check is always correct?

Comment: @BillDubuque both questions are of my interest.

Answer (score 1):

The digital root corresponds to reducing the calculation $\bmod 9$.  The integers $\bmod 9$ form a ring, so addition, subtraction, and multiplication work as you would expect.  If the original calculation is correct the digital root calculation will also be correct, but it doesn't work in the other direction.  As Matthew Daly comments, swapping two digits will not change the digital root, so you will not catch errors which swap digits.  Another example is carrying into the wrong place.  If you add $123$ and $689$, when you add $3+9=12$ you should carry the $1$ into the tens place.  If you add it into the hundreds instead, you get $902$ instead of $812$, both of which have a digital root of $2$ and you would not detect the error.

Answer (score 1):

Weighted versions in potentially weird bases, are the basis for the checking of credit card numbers, UPC and EAN barcodes, gift card numbers, SIN card numbers, Health card numbers, etc.  check digits serve as a second side of the equation.   You can use its other base forms to have fun checking Fermat's little theorem. probably even more you could use it for.